# Spark - Applying filter/map on a Dataframe using column names not working

Tags: apache-spark, dataset, apache-spark-sql

Sorry if this is a duplicate, however, the solutions pointed out aren't working for me. Most likely I am missing something basic here. I have a Dataframe like below:

```
inputDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [ts: string, id: string ... 20 more fields]
```

I am trying to filter some of the "rows" of interest here based on a field called "state" (of type String) by doing this (in Scala):

```
inputDF.filter(inputDF("state") == "BALANCED").show()
```

However this gives me an error:

```
<console>:143: error: overloaded method value filter with alternatives:
  (func: org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FilterFunction[org.apache.spark.sql.Row])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] <and>
  (func: org.apache.spark.sql.Row => Boolean)org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] <and>
  (conditionExpr: String)org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] <and>
  (condition: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
 cannot be applied to (Boolean)
       inputDF.filter(inputDF("connState") == "BALANCED").show()
```

Can someone please point out what is incorrect here ? I followed few examples including the one in https://rklicksolutions.wordpress.com/2016/03/03/tutorial-spark-1-6-sql-and-dataframe-operations/ but can't figure out whats wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I need to use === instead of ==

```
inputDF.filter(inputDF("state") === "BALANCED").show()
```

is doing what I want.

Comment: Because `inputDF("state")` returns a `org.apache.spark.sql.Column` and `==` is not defined for `Column` data type. `===` is defined to check for equality.

Comment: Agree with S.K. Furthermore, if you want to avoid being verbose and rewrite "inputDF" over and over, consider using the following notation -> `inputDF.flter( $"state" === "BALANCED").show()`